# Visualization of social network from nodes and edges arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph, social-graph

I want to visualize social networks using some tool  (preferably some tool in python). Presently, I have my data in the form of arrays: an array with information about nodes (let’s give it the name `Nodes`). Each row of this array points to a node, while each column of this array points to a specific attribute. Values in each column of `Nodes` depict attribute values. Values of zero in this `Nodes` array are representative of missing attribute values.

Alongside the nodes array, I have an array for adjacency matrix (edges). Let’s call this array `Edges`. The `Edges` array is a square array of the same size as the number of rows (nodes) in `Nodes` array. This array (`Edges`) is filled with `0` and `1` as values. A value of `0` in `(i,j)` position of `Edges` would mean that the nodes `i` and `j` are not connected to each other. Whereas, a value of `1` in `(m,n)` position would imply that nodes `m` and `n` are connected to each other.

Here is a small illustrative example of arrays `Nodes` and `Edges` with 10 nodes:

```
Nodes = np.array([[1,2,4],[1,3,1],[2,2,1],[1,1,2],
              [1,2,2],[2,1,4],[1,2,1],[2,0,1],
              [2,2,4],[1,0,4]])

Edges = np.random.randint(2, size=(10,10))
```

In the data given above, we have 10 nodes and 3 attributes. How can I get a visualization of the network using these arrays (`Nodes` and `Edges`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/). To create your graph directly from the adjacency matrix, you can use the function `from_numpy_array`.

```
import networkx as nx

adj = np.random.randint(2, size=(10,10))
G = nx.from_numpy_array(adj)
```

You can assign node attributes, but each attribute needs to have a name, which you haven't provided in your example. `set_node_attributes` makes it pretty to assign them though.

Visualizing it is also an option:

```
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is `G` in nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold') ?

Comment: The created graph (from `from_numpy_array`). I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I am wondering how we can make use of the node-attribute matrix (`Nodes`) here.

Comment: Node attributes need a name, so you'll need to come up with that first. `set_node_attributes` will be a useful function though, as I mentioned in the post.